# Enumeration of the number of splitting fields

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, galois-theory

Suppose $f(x):=x^p+ax+b\in \mathbb Z[x]$ and let $S_f$ be the minimal splitting field of $f(x)$. How can we estimate $\#\{(a,b):|S_f:\mathbb Q|=2p\}$?

Comment: I was wondering: what is the "minimal" splitting field of a polynomial?

Comment: The lowest degree extension over which $f(x)$ can split.... sometimes we call splitting field.

Comment: The term splitting field usually refers to the minimal extension in which the polynomial splits completely; this field is unique up to isomorphism. Do you mean a field in which $f$ splits at all?

Comment: No.. I donot mean that. I mean the minimal extension. However I have seen in some paper that they have used minimal. Hope you can answer the problem.

Comment: Hang on - is your question whether the (unique) splitting field has order $2p$? Your notation led me to believe you were using a different notion, one where $\#\{S_f\cdots\}$ could be greater than $1$.

Comment: I know the splitting field of a polynomial is unique. But here we have two integers $a$ and $b$ and so there only one splitting fields corresponds to each pair $(a, b)$. Thus we have to find #{(a, b): |S_f :Q|=2p with f(x)=x^p+ax+b}.

Comment: Ok. But in which case, what do you mean by the size of this set? Surely it will be infinite? For example, for $p=3$, any polynomial of the form $X^3-b$ with $|b|>1$ should work.

Comment: @Mathmo123 , that doesn't work when $b$ is a cube.

Comment: @mercio Oops of course. Nevertheless the point still stands

Comment: @Mathmo123, I need it is to be very large, but how can I interpret??